# Difference between getSeed() and generateSeed() functions in java's SecureRandom class?

Tags: java, random

What is the difference between functions `getSeed()` and `generateSeed()` in java's `SecureRandom` class?
Both looks same except that `getSeed()` returns `static byte[]` and `generateSeed()` returns only `byte[]`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`SecureRandom.getSeed(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getSeed-int-) JavaDoc ***explicitly*** says

> This method is only included for backwards compatibility. The caller is encouraged to use one of the alternative `getInstance` methods to obtain a SecureRandom object, and then call the `generateSeed` method to obtain seed bytes from that object.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getSeed-int-):

> This method is only included for backwards compatibility. The caller is encouraged to use one of the alternative getInstance methods to obtain a SecureRandom object, and then call the generateSeed method to obtain seed bytes from that object.